# Why should I use theme() function in page.tpl.php?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Im working on my first site in drupal and I have also read some basics of theming and module development. Now I am creating (overriding stark theme) my own theme, i.e. page.tpl.php and there is an theme() function called for outputting main menu items:

```
 <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t('Main menu'))); ?>
```

I roughly understand what this function is for, but why should I use it in this case? It would make sense if outputting data from module - to stylize that output by selected theme. But in this case everything I need is directly in `$main_menu` array and I can stylize it however I want, so what's the use for `theme()` function in `page.tpl.php`?

Answer (score 3):

> Why should I use theme() function in page.tpl.php?

You shouldn't.

To avoid calling theme() function in your page template, you can do this in your template.php:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['main_menu'] = theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $vars['main_menu'], 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t('Main menu')));
}
```

And then simply `print $main_menu;` in your page.tpl.php.

Comment: Answer may not provide what OP asked for, but what he needs to know right now. Plus 1 for pointing out good practices in Drupal.

Comment: It doesn't work - I add that function to template.php and `print $main_menu` is returning "Array" string. Btw. $main_menu is already defined in page.tpl.php as comment says: * - $main_menu (array): An array containing the Main menu links for the

Comment: Can you search for main_menu in your template.php? It shoud be defined there since this variable is available in your page.tpl.php. You should find, where it's defined, and override it.

Comment: By the way, where did you get page.tpl.php for your theme? As I know, Stark theme comes with no template files.

Comment: Stark has no default page.tpl.php file, therefore page.tpl.php in modules/system folder is used, and that's where I copy/pasted my template from.

Answer (score 2):

The point of using `theme('links__system_main_menu', ...)` is to re-use the existing generic `links` theme implementation of the theme. The `system_main_menu` suffix (after the two _), allow you to provide a more specific implementation of the generic `links`. If you then override the page template for the front page (ie. `page-front.tpl.php`) and for [nodes of a specific content](http://adaptivethemes.com/page-template-suggestions-per-node-type), you don't have to duplicate your HTML code. Which make it easier to maintain since you won't have to duplicate changes to multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that if you go trough drupal's theme system it gives a chance to other installed modules to do their changes - their hook functions will be called:

https://www.drupal.org/node/933976

In other words, if you don't do it "clean" way it may happen that some other's module feature won't work.